# Spelling Bee Acceptable

Tags: code-golf

This is similar to [this question](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/111287/solve-the-new-york-times-spelling-bee).
However, I have a different goal in mind:
Reduce the wordlist to words that could appear.
The easy part is to delete hyphens and similar.

The hard part, however: Remove words containing more than seven letters.

So, the problem:
Given a set of words containing only lowercase (or uppercase) ASCII letters, remove the words containing eight or more different letters.

Any input and output format is acceptable.

[Standard loophole rules](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1061/loopholes-that-are-forbidden-by-default) apply.

Shortest byte count wins.

Clever solutions are better, and faster is better as well.

My solution (implementing a quite clever O(n) algorithm, noncompetitive ref implementation):

```
#include <stdio.h>                                                              
#include <stdint.h>                                                             

int main(void) {                                                                
  char str[1024];                                                               
  while(scanf("%s\n", str) == 1) {                                              
    uint32_t st = 0;                                                            
    int s = 0;                                                                  
    for(char *p = str; *p && s <= 7; p++) {                                     
      s += ~st >> (*p - 'a') & 1;                                               
      st |= 1 << (*p - 'a');                                                    
    }                                                                           
    if(s <= 7)                                                                  
      printf("%s\n", str);                                                      
  }                                                                             
}
```

Comment: Could you include a test case?

Comment: It's generally bad practice to have an upper limit on the score.  The reason is that some languages are especially verbose or difficult to program in, and the 307 byte requirement would arbitrarily disallow them from competing.

Comment: Honestly, this is the easy part. Finding words that fit a partially revealed word is harder

Comment: I meant, this is the hard part of finding words that could ever be solutions.

Comment: I meant O(n) where n is the length of the word. In other words, to deal with a word of length n, it does O(n) work.

Answer (score 4):

## [APL (Dyalog Unicode)](https://www.dyalog.com/), 11 bytes

```apl
{⍵/⍨8>≢∪⍵}¨
```

Takes input as a list of strings.

**Explanation:**

```apl
{⍵/⍨8>≢∪⍵}¨
{       ⍵}¨ for each word
       ∪    take unique letters
    8>≢     length less than 8 as a boolean (0 or 1)
 ⍵/⍨        repeat word that many times
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT///v/pR71b9R70rLOwedS561LEKyK09tOJ/2qO2CY96@x71TfX0f9TVfGi98aO2iUBecJAzkAzx8Az@n6agrqCu8ahzwaOutkddizTVSzJSi1MVEotSFYoz8otKFMrzi1KKFXLy89JBrJKMxBKgeGlOSl5@CVAgWyEpMQ8JqgMA)

Comment: the result contains empty strings. you can fix that preserving the byte count: [`⊢(/⍨)8>≢∘∪¨`](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT////1HXIg39R70rNC3sHnUuetQx41HHqkMr/qc9apvwqLfvUd9UT/9HXc2H1hs/apsI5AUHOQPJEA/P4P9pCuoK6hqPOhc86moDmqKpXpKRWpyqkFiUqlCckV9UolCeX5RSrJCTn5cOYpVkJJYAxUtzUvLyS4AC2QpJiXlIUB0A)

Answer (score 3):

## [Perl 6](https://github.com/nxadm/rakudo-pkg), 20 bytes

```perl6
*.grep(8>*.comb.Set)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH7n1upoJamYKvwX0svvSi1QMPCTksvOT83SS84tUTzvzVXcWKlQppGdExdrIJSYlJySmpaekZmVnaOEliVJlyBUk5qSUlqUbGSjlJ@Xn5uYkl@QX5qZqJSrOZ/AA)

Filters by words that have a set of letters with size less than 8.

Answer (score 3):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), 5 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
ʒÙg8‹
```

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##NY@xbQMxDEVXMa72ANklcEHpaPkDPFEgdTHceQZ3HsW1u4yRRS6SLun@B8nH/9UpgLft@/F@po@f@2vbPifRNV5YbtPxMAncdeHM7t1GrbwUNbIxrUxFb2NyFqpX8kvXFLwic67dFEKugUTGGrmvC3IaZjZOCZ3NO8PUa0C7TYOukP58TxJJ1HBGpArNg1VMM89DwuQvose2Rl19tQRosXY4cjSe11bO/9sEBIEWTojdqrXfOwKrtVzT6Rc)

**Explanation:**

```python
ʒ        # Filter the (implicit) input-list by:
 Ù       #  Only leave distinct letters of the word
  g      #  Take its length
   8‹    #  And only leave those with a length smaller than 8
         # (And output implicitly after we're done filtering)
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 6 bytes

```
Qṫ¥Ðḟ8
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Hc6xccMwDAXQHlN4jKyRMiVIwTRyEMEDKPs0QdpskCpV2hT2ubMn0SQMlBr4//13ElnHeN1uP4/v5@d2/XoZ2/338Pw4vI0huuQTyQrC7jpTJXfI2mluamgrdMKmq8NRsF/QT4DJO1eqHRpy7QlFHNB9mbkWh8moFN5rKEKm3hPHf4GuLLsQVkZR4yNn7KwVsJlWmgDZZOc9xxXhHAaHGj1cs9G0xFj/H5g4CWujwhnUAogMLxbsHw)

#### How it works

```
Qṫ¥Ðḟ8  Main link. Argument: A (array or words)

   Ðḟ   Filterfalse; only keep the words W of A for which the chain to the left
        returns a falsy value.
  ¥         Combine the two links to the left into a dyadic chain.
Q               Unique; remove duplicate letters from W.
 ṫ   8          Tail 8; remove the first 7 letters of the result.
```

Answer (score 2):

## J, 10 bytes

```
#~8>#@~.@>
```

## explanation

```
#~ 8 > #@~.@>
#~                 NB. filter the input based on...
   8 >             NB. is 8 greater than...
       #@          NB. the length of...
         ~.@       NB. the unique characters of...
            >      NB. the unboxed input.
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y/qvpKeepmBrpaCuoKNgoGAFxLp6Cs5BPm7/less7JQd6vQc7P5rcqUmZ@QraKgnJiYmJSUlJyerW6snJxapayroWimkKaCIJyYlp6SmpWdkQtVA9Kqrw5QiSScWp6Ql5meU5xelFpRbJxbnJapzgcB/AA)

Comment: Shouldn't `9` be `8`?

Comment: Fixed.  Weird, I could have sworn the OP said 8 was the max length allowed before.  Anyway, ty...

Answer (score 2):

## Java 8, 46 bytes

```java
s->s.filter(w->w.chars().distinct().count()<8)
```

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##hVHBTsMwDL3zFVFPjaA5o21M4g677Ig4uGnWeaRxFaebJrRvH046EBIHLrEtO@89Px/gCM2h@7haD8zqFTB83imFIbm4A@vUJpdKHWTOTAm94RQdDGZbwkoChn6tbP3fBOulIF3u5OEECa3aqKCe1JWbNZsdemGsT836ZOweItfadMgJg02SWpqCxNWjvi4zwji1XhBuQEfCTg0ivZ7J3t4V6Fn39szJDYamZEZpJR9@CX2OEc5sEs3f6mDs3y7wi@ioK0@T3Tt/rh5U5ZGZBhcccy4tCcdIEWLpJgcjnUtn5yGdgPc5hzav40LKxShqUwvelzGxfhpEQSm66PoeM7abMSJxalH@9gWd0GfyWYkFTxF3aMUICgVrjBRcV1KM/iaRrYxBzo6iAEXWDC7@RtdNshx/b9OieEuj69HmkqJwzxA4iU2u0rcLy10GGGtq1nRfVVqLkcWznyssFsGdtL4d/nL9Ag)

**Explanation:**

```java
s->               // Method with String-Stream as both parameter and return-type
  s.filter(w->    //  Filter the words in the input-Stream by:
    w.chars()     //  Convert the String to characters
     .distinct()  //  Only leave distinct characters
     .count()<8)  //  Only leave words with less than 8 distinct characters
```

Comment: Wow, w.chars.distinct.count. Turn each of those words into a symbol and you have a golfing language! xD

Comment: @Quintec Hehe, it's what I do in [my 05AB1E answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/175572/52210). :) `s->s` is implicit input in 05AB1E; `filter(w->` is `ʒ`; `.chars()` is implicitly again; `.distinct()` is `Ù`; `.count()` (or length) is `g`; `<8` is `8‹`; and the closing `)` is implicitly since it's at the end of the 05AB1E program (if I wanted to do something after the filter I'd have to close it with `}`); and finally outputting is implicitly again. So my Java and 05AB1E are similar, one is a 46 bytes function and the other a 5 bytes full program, though. xD

Comment: Hehe, also basically same for my APL answer. It meets in the middle: 11 bytes :P

Answer (score 2):

## [MathGolf](https://github.com/maxbergmark/mathgolf), 6 bytes

```
Ç{▀£7>
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LY/LUcQwDIbLyWXv3Ghkh4PsKI5mFMsjKTA7XPa2HdAAnUAnNBKkwO2Tpf/hDXxtwstxfD/efz7uX59Pz8dxnVj2uiLfpsvEZCYbdjSLqYrjNkRBc@cIQ275vjD4G9gaCMWcOnYPHkDdCzDnDZjtG/WWPCu2RmmKp1zFvFDoWtoKcWae@RVYlBaq4CQ9bYZKxzmJlP9qWY0bCHiNXIoupyv1qjjv8Rn7r1@oMMnARjUm0Yg81bRrlJlefgE)

### Explanation

Really similar to the 05AB1E solution, but I lose one byte thanks to explicitly having to define the code block for filtering.

```
Ç       Implicit faulty filter by block
 {      Start block
  ▀     Get unique characters of string
   £    Get length
    7>  Is greater than 7
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 40 bytes

```python
lambda i:[x for x in i if len(set(x))<8]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HY8xcoUwDER7ncLzG6BJkSqTSU6Sn0I2MmhGWB7LJHB6IlJL@95uPfuq5fXKn89LcIszBn7/OkLWFo7AJXDgHITKaNTHY5o@3r6v2rj0kMdhGET3tJKcIGymGxUyg6SdtqoN2wmdsOppkAX7L9oKGK1zodKhomMiihig2b5xWQzmRsvCN4Y81NR6ZP9foCvLbXBXQtHGmRN21gJYmxaaAbnJrbfkV4Qfd7BbncMlNZp3L2v/BSNHYa20cAJtLvAM776KfNKLVeE@Pp7lMU3XHw)

Test cases borrowed from @Dennis. Input and output are both lists.

Answer (score 1):

## [Red](http://www.red-lang.org), 54 bytes

```
func[b][foreach a b[if 8 > length? unique a[print a]]]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PVK5jhsxDO31FYQ/YOtgi6RJulQBUhkuOBJnTEDXiuIeCPLtzpOdpBuI5DtnSLr9kHS@hP35tnuN5@1y3tsQjldi2s660yf6TFnqMa9fyKu@uBCf@9A6iS@Xy20@06/cPF4lf4SsZq1IFbMQ25TS2@DxEaZwbx8W9szzje0aeLOpVeoMnQG1cc4W2MyL1sNCGnIcumAER6PZ3BT7R5hN82IAV@Tchu4aeWqrgftoVVJgHXnRW8SUwys4FKzA0RqHJIdYuwvcdMvauhwaQxsgwI06nMnvEAy2viOJQtqhilIDG5nCdZFJsVWTOGX6IE7aFaf1IMlYMElYJ1G30hI9UiCwa9LkyM0nZd4ATkC6AwsVPioTZwTMT/RzklQtgCYEgg/YUC704mpUEcfwRPIuI@q82yfPmUtsD@C1pKaL6I6oHcskDNkFktpDPpjmE31dkOxTSIdDyMOoVhrSh1ylJhkwhYfXlr2DTqBm@VztUNSc/8UDP067H8qT6hJEndEBMnqib@9R@hRfGSKCFiMLmqPoXRPPdQEX6FATGiNbOYEzeu68bFPbUbUyJTEZa1paXip4xaNIw/6m6gX17WR9TQErbxmVhscvezr9Hxmd6HT7Aw)

The first test set was taken from Dennis'

Answer (score 1):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), <strike>104</strike> 95 bytes

Dennis's word set was also used here.

Thanks to nwellnhof for the suggestions.

```c
char*s,*t;f(i,j,k){for(;~scanf("%ms",&s);i<8&&puts(s))for(i=j=0,t=s;*t;j=k)k=j|1<<*t++,i+=j<k;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Hc5RT4MwFAXg9/4KssSFbizRNxPgobCO3aRrSW/R7JFgmAW3mRX1Yc6fLhaf7znnu83q0DTj2LzWl4WLFkPchjbqop5e2/MljH9cU5/acHZ3dLNo7mhsk8f5/P1jcKGjdIrYtEvvoyF1sS93aU/7tPt@SJLFsFxGdpl2SR/fRnsagmNtT@Hn2b7Q4Bq0IY2D2yhUlW@52BMBiGrHJUckuTJ8VyrN9J4Yzkq1R7IRzDwz3BKWoQHJpSElA2kyJgQShljtQBZI1poXBUwz3Je0QpOBzxfEKBCT4K2cCaVhAzkzoCRhpVaSrwkDLSYec39l5Mkb4FW/AzLXfF35Z/H/wQwyAarkBeREaQ/4DlTas79N@1Yf3Lj6@gM)

Comment: [96 bytes](https://tio.run/##Hc5RT4MwFAXg9/4KssQFNpbom0nhobCO3aRrSW/R7JFgmAW3mRX1Yc6fLhaf7znnu83q0DTj2LzWl4WLFwO1cRf3tA2ja3u@hPTHNfWpDWd3RzeL5y6iNnmcz98/Bhe6KJoiNu3S@3hIHfXtLu2jPu2@H5JkMSyXsV2mXdLT22hPQ3Cs7Sn8PNuXKLgGXqDBbRSqyrdc7IkARLXjkiOSXBm@K5Vmek8MZ6XaI9kIZp4ZbgnL0IDk0pCSgTQZEwIJQ6x2IAska82LAqYZ7ktaocnA5wtiFIhJ8FbOhNKwgZwZUJKwUivJ14SBFhOPub8y8uQN8KrfAZlrvq78s/j/YAaZAFXyAnKitAd8Byrt2d@mfasPblx9/QE "C (gcc) – Try It Online"), if you're OK with implementation- and undefined behavior.

Comment: @nwellnhof What's a little UD between friends for code golf? :-)

Answer (score 1):

## JavaScript, 33 bytes

```
a=>a.filter(s=>new Set(s).size<8)
```

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##LY87bsMwDIavUniygdZzhjqX6Fh0oGVaYUGTAiknSC/vUm63jyL/h77hDp6MSn0TXfBYpwOmK4wrcUXrfboKPl4@sPY@jE4/@H4ZjqTiyjiy5n7tPzvWPd2Qn91rx@SuGwq6x5S04lbUwNquIhR9tveVoT7Ab4EweyVBqcEFSOoMzO0G3PeNJDdeDHOmZoqn3NTrTKHLzVaJW@aZn4DVaKUElVSaTTEVXBqR8V8tT3EDAffIpehyupIkw2WPz/h//ZlmJi2YKcWkFpGnmnaLMt3XMBy/), using Dennis' test cases

Answer (score 1):

## [C# (.NET Core)](https://www.microsoft.com/net/learn/dotnet/what-is-dotnet), 58 bytes

```
 a=>a.Where(x=>x.GroupBy(y=>y).Count()<8)
```

[Try It Online!](https://tio.run/##XVCxTsMwEJ3xV5w62VLJjJQmAxVUSCAhGDoghrNzaQyODbZTGlX59mCiFFCfPNy9e/d0fipcKudp7IK2O3juQ6Q2Z/@7bO2MIRW1syHbkCWv1ZniXtvPnCmDIcAjHBkkhIhRK9g7XcEDastFGkyTH9x2Vq1C9Mnk5XUJdze2a8mjNDSzZQkSoIARixKzbUOe@KEoD9nGu@7juud9UfYi3dbZyMXqSow5uzgZgkqblr5SdYQFSlVRvWv027szoWprt1gmdoacMDGhSm@qZJgbGPLfm@uUE6oG@B49oARtQXIlxPzhE9YpJ2co23odKSVDHKX4cxnYufCJsJp0s2pgw/gN)

Answer (score 1):

## [C++ (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), <s>105</s> 104 bytes

```cpp
#import<bits/stdc++.h>
f(){for(char*n;~scanf("%ms",&n);)std::set<int>(n,n+strlen(n)).size()<8&&puts(n);}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HY7LTsMwEEXXzFegIqqEPtiipqrkpG46kmtHtgPqMoSkjdS6URxYgODTCVO2M/eec8u2nR3KchjumnN76frla9P7R9@/lZPJ/LiCOgi/6ksXlMeie3DRjy8LVwej@7MfTccujEKKLha@6peN61eBm7qJ77tT5QIXhnPffFZBuHwaj9v33tMp@h4od3suGkdguCF8BN@DUHmy5WIPAo1ROy65MZAoy3eZ0kzvwXKWqb2BjWD2hZktsNhYlFxayBhKGzMhDDBj8h3K1MBa8zTFK4ZTSStjY6R8ClahuBrIlTChNG4wYRaVBJZpJfkaGGpx1ZuEvgyeyYFkJQ7KRPN1TmPN/8AYY4Eq4ykmoDQJqIO5Ju1vWZ@Kgx9mdVt158b75qP6Aw)

-1 byte thanks to @ceilingcat

Answer (score 1):

## perl -nlE, 32 bytes

```
my%h;@h{/./g}=();say if keys%h<8
```

This reads words from `STDIN`, printing out those with less than 7 different characters.

Comment: 25 bytes: `my%h;@h{/./g}=1;%h<8&&say` (`%h<8` requires Perl 5.26)

Answer (score 0):

## [Racket](https://racket-lang.org/), 95 bytes

```
(require racket/set)(define(f l)(filter(lambda(x)(<(set-count(list->set(string->list x)))8))l))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NVAxcsMwDNvzCp87VBpyXTv08hdKph1eadEl6TZ5fUq56QZQIABRoX6iP14Y2jLoQd4KGD6S4tdOiv9DQ89pwpkapnngnGZiR00Ma5kg3XL6SKE5V9mbJybz8yV4Mldqy/nSJ8Mt5/yeM@f8eHoNHOPXNLLs9Yp8H4cxlCYrNjQLVsVx3URB@5sjbHLv85nBf8CuAaGYh1XzwBtQ8wLMXQNm@xrpHU@Ky0LdFI91FfNCsbd0WyHumUd@BRalmSo4Ses2m0rDqSNS/qtlNTQQ4DtyKbocrtSq4rTHZ@xZv1Bhkg0XqsFEI/LYpl17mTHn0ylNZBvDfeiHNY/j/AI)

The test set was taken from Dennis'

Answer (score 0):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 12 bytes

```
ΦＡ›⁸ＬΦι⁼μ⌕ιλ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NVAxbsMwDPyK4ckB3L1A56Yo0KF7kIGWGZsATaqklCKvdyW50XRHno5HhhUsKPC@fxtJGs7ECW34lJjTcBq7D0Oohdex@0JZ0vpU0Ni9/2RgH7axO5PMtcKn473t@@XSs@awIj/6seuZ3HVDQfdKg0rCLaqBtXZCiPporRtD@gVfK4bJEwlKqiRCCTgBc5OBe95IlkZmw2Whao6Hh6mnicrfpbkrcZ1@RAnAanSjAIlUmlc0FZwbJOP/jB6KDCq6lwRUYh3mJMFwzmU7f64z0cSkERcKlaqV2YcF5XJW7K/X/eXOfw) Link is to verbose version of code. Explanation:

```
 Ａ              Input array
Φ               Filter strings where
   ⁸            Literal 8
  ›             Is greater than
    Ｌ           Length of
      ι         Current string
     Φ          Filtered on characters where
        μ       Inner index
       ⁼        Equals
           λ    Current character's
         ⌕      First index in
          ι     Current string
                Implicitly print matching strings
```

Comment: [10?](https://tio.run/##NZCxbsQwCIZfJfKUk9K9Uue2qtShU5fTDdjhHCRiIrBT3dOnttN6gh/88UNYQIMAH8eXUsrjG3FGHT/SVvJ4mYZ3RWjC8zR8Yop5GV934FK1b1ACzzg6w@ymgS7tvRzH9epYSliQH1V2TGayYkKzlgZJGddNFLSXM8Imj166M@QfsKXF4C1TwtTIboNqzQNzbwOzslKKPZkVY6QGx5OhYtlT/Rs7XYjb9NNKABalOwXIJKmzNpWEcw9J@c@jhdoGLdqrA6q2TjiloDiXup39r@PJM8mGkUJLRevsE0GlHhTd7XY87fwL)

Answer (score 0):

## JavaScript (ES6), 53 bytes

Without [using a set](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/175590/58563):

```javascript
a=>a.filter(w=>[...w].every(o=c=>o[c]=o[c]||--k,k=8))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NZBBjoMwDEWvMmJFpcJ6NulFEAsTTOqpGyM7UFXq3ZkkzGyi/2Xn@ds/sIN5pTV1UWY8FneAu0G/ECfU9uVuQ9/3r7HHHfXdivPuJoMfXXk@n657XB/u@3I5vEQTxp4ltEs7NCybvyO/m@tXw2QmT4xoVqyXhM9VFLRWE8Iq71pZGNIL7F40TJYoYkzFrEAxTcBc28Bse1IM1cyKIVBh48lQsTRR/hsqXYjL8DOJBxalhTwkklhZq0rEuUpS/otoPrdBUXtOQDnWCafoFectL2f/20w0McmKgXyxonn2iaBNc65mzNf5BQ) (using Dennis' test set)

Answer (score 0):

## Japt `-f`, 6 bytes

```
¬â Ê<8
```

[Try it](https://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.4.6&code=rOIgyjw4&input=WyJsb3VjaGVseSIsImxpc3NvbWVuZXNzIiwiY290ZW1wb3JhcnkiLCJ0ZWFwb3lzIiwiZmxhdHdhc2giLCJhYnN0aW5lbnQiLCJwYWludGJhbGxzIiwiYXNzdW1pbmdzIiwiZHJlZ2dpbmVzc2VzIiwiZnJvc3RiaXRpbmciLCJ0b2lsc29tZWx5IiwiY2Fsb3JpZmljYXRpb24iLCJhcHJvbmVkIiwiYWlybGVzcyIsInNjb3JpYSIsInZlbnRpbGF0ZXMiLCJpbmNyZWR1bG91c25lc3MiLCJiaWJsaW9wZWdpYyIsIm9yYml0Iiwic2NpdXJpbmUiXQotZg==), using Dennis' test cases

Answer (score 0):

## Snap! 4, scratchblocks2 syntax

(pretending that Snap! exclusive blocks are valid in scratchblocks2 but functions use the Scratch `define`)

## 69 bytes

`b` takes a list of strings.

```
define((b)
report((#)keep items such that(<(length of [])<[7]>)from(b
```